# Removing second primer sequence from FASTQ

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I've got FASTQ files from a sequencing run and I'm trying to remove the sequence of the second indexing primer with Unix. Below are the first few lines of the FASTQ file. I'm trying to remove `+AGCGCGAT` from the first line, `+AGCTCGCG` from the fifth line, etc. Essentially, it's removing a plus sign and any eight characters (`A`, `C`, `G`, `T`, or `N`) following it. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
@NS500663:433:HGFVKBGX2:1:11101:2828:1039 1:N:0:CGAGTGCT+AGCGCGAT
TCTGGNAACTTGGCTGATTCACTGGCCACGATACCTCATGTCCTCATCCATCAGGATTATCAGCTGCATAGACGG
+
AAAAA#EEEEEEEEEEEEEA/EEEEEE/EE6E/E/E///E//6EE///EA/////E/E/</E/A6/<E////6//
@NS500663:433:HGFVKBGX2:1:11101:8765:1039 1:N:0:ATCACGAT+AGCTCGCG
CATGTNAAATGAAATACATGGGAGACAAATATTTTTACTTATATAGAGTAGTTTCTCAAGGATTTTATAAATACA
+
AAAAA#EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEAEAEAEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

Comment: Would it be correct to say you'd like to remove _all_ text from the `+` onwards on _all_ lines that start with `@` in the whole file? Or do you just want to remove these two specific strings from these two specific lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/^\(@.*\)+.*$/\1/' file.fastq >new-file.fastq
```

This will remove the primer sequence and the `+` from those lines.

It will find all lines starting with `@` and containing a `+` sign. It will replace the line with only the bit before the `+` sign, and drop the rest.

The input is from `file.fastq` and the output will go to `new-file.fastq`.

The following is a bit more restrictive in that it explicitly matches the characters that you mentioned after the `+`:

```
$ sed 's/^\(@.*\)+[ACGTN]*$/\1/' file.fastq >new-file.fastq
```